# Can we have fineuploader traditional and azure together

Tags: jquery, azure, fine-uploader

previously we used to have fineuploader version called custom, which was a jquery wrapper and we had both azure upload to blob  + traditional upload to your server

in the new version 5.2 when I call the fineUploader() method to upload to our own server it gives out errors.

Answer (score 0):

Please use Use 5.3.0 version

```
if (qq.supportedFeatures.ajaxUploading) {
    var uploader = new qq.azure.FineUploader
        request: {
            endpoint: 'https://{ YOUR_STORAGE_ACCOUNT_NAME }.blob.core.windows.net/{ YOUR_CONTAINER_NAME }'
        },
        signature: {
            endpoint: '/signature'
        },
        uploadSuccess: {
            endpoint: '/success'
        }
    });
}
```

Click for Link http://docs.fineuploader.com/quickstart/02-setting_options-azure.html

Answer (score 0):

Yes, as of Fine Uploader 5.3, you can download a single build that contains the S3, Azure, and traditional endpoint modules. From the 5.3 blog post:

> [We’ve made it easier to use Fine Uploader in an environment that switches between Azure, S3, and traditional endpoints](https://github.com/FineUploader/fine-uploader/issues/1144#issuecomment-123803619). Starting with version 5.3, you can now [download](http://fineuploader.com/customize.html) a single build of Fine Uploader that contains support for all three endpoint types. Simple select the new “S3 + Azure + traditional” option in the server type section.

Note that you *cannot* download a jQuery wrapped version of that build, but [there is no benefit in using the jQuery wrapper](https://github.com/FineUploader/fine-uploader/issues/1310) anyway.

Comment: thanks a lot . I had the jquery wrapper, changing it to the new all-fine-uploader.